# Laravel 4 pulling data from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have table called 'players'. I want to pull every player from the database, or simply select players that have in column 'online' = 1. I want to display their name (column 'name') in 'players' table.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    public function online()
{
  $results = Player::with('online')->find(1)
  return View::make('aac.test')->with('results', $results);
}
```

also tried:

```
    public function online()
{
  $results = DB::select('select * from players where level = 1');
  return View::make('aac.test')->with('results', $results);
}
```

None of them works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function online()
{
  $results = Player::where('online', 1)->get('name');
  return View::make('aac.test')->with('results', $results);
}
```

To display it using blade:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($results as $result)
        <li>
            {{$result->name}}
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: It works now, so I need to include the get method or w/e it is for working pulling data? Also how could I only display their name? Should I do something like this?

`<?php foreach($results->players as $player):?> 
 <?php echo $player->name ?>
 <?php endforeach;?> `

Comment: You already have your list of players in that collection. Just edited to show you how.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1508618/alexander-cogneau proposed to use pluck('name') to retrieve just the name column from your table, but I think that pluck() just return the first record, but you can also do it using `get('name')` or `get(array('id','name))`. Edited.

Comment: hi, sorry for disturbing, I would like to ask you a question. How could I say when there's no players online (no id's of 1 in column 'online) There is no players online. ?

Comment: if empty($results) then you have no records of online users.

Comment: well I've tried, how could I implement it to this: 
 `<tbody>
    <?php $count = 0;?> 
@foreach($results as $result)
  <?php $count++;?>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $count }}. </td>
      <td>{{ $result->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $result->created_at }}</td>
      <td>{{ $result->group_id }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>`

Comment: How could I make to display There is no character online? I've tried adding echo but it just won't display:P

Comment: This should work: http://paste.laravel.com/DEu. But `<?php echo "..."; ?>` in place of {{}} must work too.

Comment: It still doesn't display. :S

Comment: Because you're trying to show it inside a tbody and not a <td>. Fix your HTML and it will show.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I've done it like this, here's also my full code: http://paste.laravel.com/DEC

Comment: Don`t you need a <tr> before a <td>?

Comment: I've done it like this:  `<tr>
    <td>{{"There are no users online."}}</td>
  </tr>`

still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function online()
{
  $results = Player::where('level','=','1')->get();
  return View::make('aac.test')->with('results', $results);
}
```

To display it using blade:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($results as $result)
        <li>
            {{$result->name}}
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```